# Yoast SEO Primary Category Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, seo

My aim is to create a pagination, where pagination goes through the posts in the same category when they have only one category, and through the primary category where there are more categories for one post.

My code so far:

```
<?php
        $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', get_the_id() );
        $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
        $term = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
        $cat_name = $term->name;

?>
            <div class='pagination <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->slug ; } ?>'>
                <span class='prev bg'><?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'Előző hír', TRUE, $cat_name); ?></span>

                <?php echo $cat_name ?>

                <span class='next bg'><?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Következő hír', TRUE, $cat_name); ?></span>
            </div>
```

In the previous_post_link and next_post_link methods what should I write instead of the variable witch holds the name of the primary category of the post?